# Which presentation of a 3-manifold group comes from a Heegaard splitting?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Given a balanced presentation of a three-manifold group G, is there any way to determine whether it comes from a Heegaard splitting? In other words, how to characterize such presentations? There exist Seifert fibered example (by Boileau and Zieschang) and hyperbolic example (by Tao Li) for which the rank of the fundamental group is strictly smaller than the Heegaard genus of the three-manifold. Clearly not every presentation comes from a Heegaard splitting.

For general groups, there exist obstructions for a balanced presentation to be the fundamental group of a three-manifold (for example, see [obstruction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294655/obstructions-to-realizing-a-balanced-presentation-as-a-3-manifold-group)). Berge's famous program [heegaard](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/) can construct a Heegaard diagram from a group presentation, provided that the presentation is realizable. However, it does not help to characterize such presentations.