# Example of a non $\pi_1$-injective, degree one, self-map of a three-manifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 3-manifolds

All manifolds will be assumed to be closed, oriented, and connected.

Let $f\colon M\to M$ be a map of degree $\pm 1$. It is not hard to show that $\pi_1(f)$ is surjective.

> What is an example of a *non* $\pi_1$-injective, degree one, self-map of a three-manifold?

If $\dim(M) = 2$, then $\pi_1(f)$ is injective because the fundamental group of any surface is residually finite, and any finitely generated residually finite group is Hopfian.

If $\dim(M) = 3$ and if $M$ is either a spherical, or hyperbolic, or Haken manifold, then again $\pi_1(M)$ is Hopfian.  Thus $\pi_1(f)$ is injective.

A related conjecture is the [Hopf conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture#Self-maps_of_degree_1).

Comment: Are you asking whether the Hopf conjecture is true?

Comment: I know it is not generally valid, but I have no counter-example. I am looking for an example of a degree one map $f\colon M\to M$, where $M$ is a closed, oriented, connected, **three-manifold** such that $\pi_1(f)\colon \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(M)$ is not injective.

Comment: Doesn't Hopf conjecture state precisely that such a map doesn't exist?

Comment: You can add spherical manifolds to the list of non-examples (as finite groups are Hopfian).

Comment: @Wojowu I added a reference link of Hopf conjecture.

Comment: Are you asking for an example of a 3-manifold for which the Hopf conjecture is unknown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the book [Three-manifold groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202) we find a giant flow chart showing what is known to follow from the assumption that $N$ is an irreducible, compact, orientable three-manifold with empty or toroidal boundary (such that $\pi_1(N)$ is neither finite nor solvable).  As one particular consequence, such manifolds are Hopfian.

Manifolds with finite fundamental group are Hopfian, so those are dealt with. Three-manifolds with solvable fundamental group are toroidal, thus Haken, and so dealt with. Three-manifolds which are reducible have fundamental group being a free product.  However, residually finiteness passes is preserved under taking free products.  So reducible manifolds are dealt with.  (See, for example, Hempel's paper [Residual finiteness for three-manifold groups](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400882083-018/html).)

Thus all closed, oriented, and connected three-manifolds have fundamental group being Hopfian.

---

Further references: [a mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61661)

Comment: Thanks for your excellent and clear answer.

Comment: :) You are welcome.